# detect when a ship change draught to over 11 meters from under 11 mesters

Tags: java, esper

Working with ESPER CEM and maritime ais tracks. I want to detect when a ship change draught to over 11 meters from under 11 mesters.

```
select new from pattern [every new=VoyageReport(draught < 11) -> (VoyageReport(mmsi=new.mmsi and draught > 11))]
```

**Server messege:**Statement already destroyed

**Source:** http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.4.0/doc/reference/en/html/index.html

hoping somone can help me im pretty new to this.

Best regards Peter

Answer (score 0):

"Statement already destroyed" is a statement management issue and has nothing to do with the specific EPL statement. It means that a statement was destroyed and the statement object your code uses is no longer usable.